# Binding an 'unsigned long' (uint64) in an sqlite3 statement? C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, bind, unsigned-integer

I'm using the sqlite3 library that is available at [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

I have some unsigned longs that I would like store in a database. I do not want to construct the query myself and leave it open to some sort of injection (whether it be accidental or not). Thus, I'm using the [`sqlite_bind_*`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to 'sanitize' my parameters.

The issue is that there isn't a function type for unsigned long integers, just integers.

`int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int);`

`int sqlite3_bind_int64(sqlite3_stmt*, int, sqlite3_int64);`

I am definitely going to have numbers that will overflow if I am unable to store them in an unsigned manner.

Am I going to need to manage this myself? (i.e. casting to an unsigned type after selecting from the db or casting to signed type before inserting into database)

If I do have to manage this myself, how would one do some comparison queries that are stored as a signed long integer when the comparisons are really meant to be in the unsigned range?

Looking at the [INTEGER datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that get converted, one would think that unsigned longs could be represented without issue.

If there are other solutions available, please enlighten me! 
Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this same problem and I solved it by treating the unsigned 64-bit hash as a signed 64-bit value for the purpose of putting it into the database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you wanted to store a uint64_t in a sqlite database and still allow it to be used as a uint64_t in SQL, then you're probably going to need to write some custom functions.

You simply need to cast the uint64_t to an int64_t when sending to and from the database, and then write a custom function to perform whatever comparison etc. you need.  For example, to do a greater than comparison:

```
void greaterThan( sqlite3_context* ctx, sqlite3_value** values )
{
    uint64_t value1 = boost::numeric_cast< uint64_t >( sqlite3_value_int64( value[ 0 ] ) );
    uint64_t value2 = boost::numeric_cast< uint64_t >( sqlite3_value_int64( value[ 1 ] ) );
    sqlite3_result_int( ctx, value1 > value2 );
}

//Register this function using sqlite3_create_function
sqlite3_create_function( db, "UINT_GT", 2, SQLITE3_ANY, NULL, &greaterThan, NULL, NULL );
```

Then to use this in SQL:

```
SELECT something FROM aTable WHERE UINT_GT(value1,value2);
```

Alternatively, if you need custom collation based on uint64_t, you should be able to use sqlite3_create_collation in a similar manner.

It's not a perfect solution as you'll need to write a custom function for every operation you want to do, but it should at least work.

Answer (score 15):

An SQLite database does not have the ability to store unsigned 64-bit integers in it. It's just a limitation of the data.

Your options are:

- Store it as a string, converting as needed.
- Store it as a binary blob, converting as needed.
- Pretend that it is a signed 64-bit integer with a cast, thus converting as necessary.
- Store two pieces of information as two columns: the unsigned 63-bit integer (the lower 63-bits), and a value that represents the high bit.

Since these are hashes, you probably don't care about comparisons other than equality testing. So most of these methods would work just fine for you.

Comment: But this page (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/int64.html) explicitly mentions the `sqlite3_uint64` type, what is going on here?@!

Comment: @Michael: What's going on is that SQLite declares an unsigned 64-bit type. That doesn't mean you can store it in a table. [The docs make it quite clear](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that INTEGER values are always signed integers, up to 64-bits in size.

Answer (score 1):

`uint32_t` fits entirely inside of a `int64_t` without any worries, so you can do a simple assignment.

```
    int64_t i64;
    uint32_t u32 = 32;
    i64 = u32;
```

Assigning the other way you *should* check the bounds of the `int64_t` so that any changes made to the value inside of the database are caught early.

```
    int64_t i64 = 32;
    uint32_t u32;
    if (i64 < 0 || i64 > std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid uint32_t");
    u32 = i64;
```

You can then send your `int64` to the sqlite database as you normally would.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no control over my source of data and having values outside of int64 are very possible. Sure I could store the data without issue, but doing comparison queries would not be possible.  If my data would fit in an `int64` I would have not had any issues and would have not asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of different approaches, mainly trying to get the column type to work as a sqlite3_uint64 as explained at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/int64.html

Had no luck as the uint64 was not stored as a uint64 in the table. When I looked at the stored data it was signed, so I assumed it was stored as int64.

I ended up prefixing the value with a single char to force sqlite to store it as text without any conversion taking place. It was much easier to just add the char to the select query value for comparison. Thus 9223360144090060712 became A9223360144090060712, and I could simply do a SELECT WHERE HASH = 'A9223360144090060712'

Answer (score 0):

it is a hack but int and unsigned have the same bit depth so you could

```
int i=static_cast<int>(unsigned_int);
```

and convert it back

```
unsigned unsigned_int=static_cast<unsigned>(i);
```

to be on the safe side on your plaftform

```
static_assert(sizeof(int)==sizeof(unsigned));
```

or use the width specific

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t
int32_t
```

Comment: I think if you are stuck with a db that dosent support unsigned int a little hack like this is the least of your concerns.  not sure if you would even have to convert before writing to db as all unsigned does is change the meaning of one bit.

Comment: This isn't a great idea when you want to use anything other than basic SQL on the values.  SQLite will think that any large uints are actually negative numbers.  So ordering and comparisons go out the window.  To say nothing of accidentally forgetting casts and the like.

Comment: That is true, if you are going to be comparing on the value it will cause problems, if  your are just using SQLite as a storage file I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @111111 I'd agree with you if there wasn't another easy solution that gets round that particular problem.  No sense in limiting your ability to use the power of SQL - even if you've no use for it now you never know when that might change.

Comment: g++ gives me `invalid cast` on both of those conversions.

Comment: I can only apoligise they should be static casts I am surprised it didn't work though.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I've found that the easiest way to deal with this problem while still allowing the database to perform comparisons etc. is to store unsigned integers in the database using the `sqlite3_bind_int64` function.  I'm assuming that you are using 32 bit unsigned integers, which can easily be stored in a 64 bit signed integer.

For example:

```
uint32_t x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
sqlite3_bind_int64( stmt, 1, x );
```

Then to retrieve your variable (assuming you're using boost, otherwise you'll have to write your own overflow check code):

```
 #include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
 ...
 uint32_t x = boost::numeric_cast< uint32_t >( sqlite3_column_int64( stmt, 0 ) );
```

Of course this falls apart if you want to store unsigned int64s, but that's a bit of a limitation of sqlite.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no control over my source of data and having values outside of int64 are very possible. Sure I could store the data without issue, but doing comparison queries would not be possible.  If my data would fit in an `int64` I would have not had any issues and would have not asked the question.

Comment: @g19fanatic Ah, my mistake - I assumed by unsigned integer you just meant a uint32_t.  You might want to look at an alternative database backend if you can't live with the casting option.

Comment: My fault actually, not being specific enough

Comment: @g19fanatic I am a little curious what kind of numbers you're storing that could be larger than 2^63 though.  I take it using a double instead would not be good enough?  Suppose another alternative might be to store the number in a blob (or even just a plain int64), and write custom SQL functions using sqlite3_create_function to do SQL comparisons/ordering/whatever

Comment: My data source(fpga recording 4 sensors worth of data) creates a hash which is converted to an uint64. This hash has the possibility to be over 2^63 and I'm looking for a way to mitigate that situation.  Creating a custom sql function is something new that hasn't been proposed and honestly something that escaped me. If you put that as a new answer and expand a lil bit, I'll mark that as correct as every other answer doesn't correctly provide a solution.